# Python: converting iterable to list: 'list(x)' vs. full slice 'x[:]'

Tags: python, list, slice

I wonder if there is any difference in these two ways to convert an iterable to a list in Python:

- using the `list()` constructor:

  ```
  my_list = list(my_iterable)
  ```
- using a full slice:

  ```
  my_list = my_iterable[:]
  ```

Are there differences in the implementation? If so, what about performance? Any changes in Python 2 vs. Python 3?

Of course I realize that the constructor version is much better readable though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`list(thing)` gives you a list.

`thing[:]` could give you any type it wants.

In other words, the second option only works with specific types (and you haven't mentioned which types you're actually working with).

Edit: A useful feature of `thing[:]` is that when it is supported it usually results in a reference to "all the elements of the thing" which can be modified without changing which object `thing` points to.  For example:

```
thing[:] = [1,2,3]
```

Will assign `[1,2,3]` over top of whatever was in `thing`, even if that's not a list per se.  Whereas:

```
list(thing) = [1,2,3]
```

Is nonsense, and:

```
thing = [1,2,3]
```

Makes `thing` refer to a new list, regardless of its previous type.

Comment: I normally always use `list(thing)` and the full slice was just something I had seen occasionally at Code Golf. So I actually did not really know that the slice operator only works on a limited subset of iterables. Thanks for the lesson, I'll just go on and keep using `list(thing)` as always. But is there any real need for the full slicing operator `[:]` then? Calling `list(my_list)` also creates a new instance with different `id`.

Comment: @ByteCommander: The main use of `[:]` in the real world is to assign in-place all the elements of a list or array.  For example, `x = [1,2,3]; x = [4,5,6]` creates an entirely different object for `x` to refer to the second time around.  But `x = [1,2,3]; x[:] = [4,5,6]` leaves `x` referring to the same list object, and overwrites the contents.  This is often useful in NumPy for example.  I've updated my answer to reflect some of this.

Comment: Oh, cool! I haven't heard of assigning to a slice yet. Thanks for these insights.

Answer (score 10):

Not everything supports slicing, e.g. generators:

```
(x for x in range(5))[:]   # raises an error
```

So `list` is more general. `[:]` is a mostly just a way to copy a list.

The main reason `[:]` is possible is because it's what you get when you combine leaving out the index before the colon (e.g. `[:3]`) and leaving out the index after, both of which are useful by themselves. It's also useful if you add a step, e.g. `[::-1]` is a common way to reverse a string. `[:]` is not very useful by itself for a list but it is slightly faster for certain situations as I've commented on Padriac's answer, although readability is usually more important than such micro-optimisations.

For non-lists, `[:]` could theoretically do anything depending on what you tell it to:

```
class A(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return 3

print A()[:]  # prints 3
```

But you should probably avoid such definitions.

Comment: Is there any real need for the full slicing operator `[:]` then? Calling `list(my_list)` also creates a new instance with different `id`, which is the same behaviour the slicing has.

Answer (score 1):

I presume *my_iterable* is always a list or a subclass of list or both methods could produce completely different results:

In python2 calling list is slightly faster than slicing:

```
In [2]: l = list(range(1000000))

In [3]: timeit l[:]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop

In [4]: timeit list(l)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.45 ms per loop
```

Python3 has very similar results:

```
In [1]: l = list(range(1000000))

In [2]: timeit list(l)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.54 ms per loop

In [3]: timeit l[:]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
```

`[:]` is used to slice all the elements from anything that supports slicing, trying to compare calling  `list` or using `[:]` outside of when  `my_iterable` is a list makes no real sense as they both do very different things based on what you use them on.

```
In [2]: i = (1,2,3,4,5)

In [3]: list(i)
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [4]: i[:]
Out[4]: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

In [5]: i = "hello world"

In [6]: list(i)
Out[6]: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']

In [7]: i[:]
Out[7]: 'hello world'
```

Comment: If you change the beginning to `range(10)` then the results are reversed. `[:]` avoids looking up the name `list` so if you have to make many copies of small lists it's faster.